# Jquery key press is being fired too early

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have a searchbar.  If i type something in that searchbar i want to compare the input of the seachbar to the names in my string in real time:

this array contains the word hundai:
    allRowsArray[0][1];

This is my javascript code:

```
   jQuery("#carsearchbar").keypress(function(){
    carname = allRowsArray[0][1];
    var searchword = jQuery("#carsearchbar").val();
    jQuery("#logger").text(carname.startsWith(searchword)+"|"+carname +"|"+searchword+"|"+searchword.length+"");
    });

I type h and it immediately outputs:        true|hundai||0|     
If i type hu it immediately  displays:   true|hundai|h|1|
```

As you can see the keypess firing is being performed before the number or value is added to the input field. So lets say i want to look for the word hundai in my array i have to type hundai and a space behind it. Or it wil only search "hunda" without the i.

Is there a way around this? Maybe a delay? A delay sounds like bad form.

Comment: What is `foodname`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to change it.

Comment: Provide a live example.

Comment: @user2322791 got you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `keypress` so that you get the current character you just pressed from the `val()` for that element:

```js
var allRowsArray = [['someName','hundai']];
jQuery("#carsearchbar").keyup(function(){
  carname = allRowsArray[0][1];
  var searchword = jQuery("#carsearchbar").val();
  jQuery("#logger").text(carname.startsWith(searchword)+"|"+carname +"|"+searchword+"|"+searchword.length+"");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='carsearchbar' type-'text' />

<span id='logger'></span>
```

Comment: The answer was so simple. I'm such an idiot. Could've have checked that myself. Thanx for the help :)